# Run Git Shell in current command prompt?

Tags: git-shell

I like the [Git Shell](http://windows.github.com/) because it allows me to run popular linux commands in my windows environment. [My IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) allows me to run command-line programs inside an embedded console, which I also quite like. I was hoping I could use the Git Shell from inside this console, but when I run the command as specified in the shortcut icon it created,

> C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell

It just opens a new command prompt rather than using the current one. Is there a way to force it to use the current prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the git shell in current command prompt you execute

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

[image]

---

To execute a command in git shell and have it return output, you do

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -c <your command>
```

I have it also set up with Sublime Text's plugin Shell Turtlestein
<sup><sub><sup>actual setting: `{"surround_cmd": ["\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" --login -c ' ", " ' "]}`</sup></sub></sup>
[image: and it works flawlessly]

See if you can plug that command like that in your IDE to make it work

Comment: Weird. When I opened my settings today it had this in it: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"` so either I figured it out (and forgot), or something installed it for me. Not sure what the difference between your command and mine is, but both seem to work.